# Associate a Module to a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have this Module to run some events in **Worksheet B**. All Range used in this module refers to those cells in **Worksheet B**.

However, I would like to place the Button to run this module in **Worksheet A**. Is there a single-line header code or something to add so that all the Range will always refer to those in **Worksheet B**. Understand that alternatively, I could add 'Sheets(B).Range(#)' to every Range, however, this doesn't look Neat.

Below is the snippet of my Code. Thanks for your help.

```
Sub X_Iterate_Member()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo Error

Dim i As Integer, X As Integer

'------------------------Pre-guess X_value to be 0.5h-------------
For i = 4 To 11
    Range("B" & i) = Range("E" & i).Value * 0.5
Next i


'------------------------Iteration Loop---------------------------
i = 4 'Reset i to be 4-th Row

Do While i < 11 ' Working on Row 4 to 11

    Do While i < 11
        If Range("B" & i) <> "" And Range("J" & i) <> 0 Then Exit Do
    i = i + 1
    Loop

If Range("B" & i) = "" Or Range("J" & i) = 0 Then GoTo Increment
Range("Q" & i).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("B" & i)
```

Comment: Surround your code by a `With Sheet1` - `End With` structure and prefix all `Range` references by a point `.` to fully qualify them, i.e. `.Range(...` instead of `Range(...` :-)

Comment: And change your `On Error GoTo Error` line. `Error` is a reserved word in VBA and should not be used as a lable to jump to. Call it something else: `On Error GoTo Error_Handling`. Also note that row and column counts are of type `Long` not `Integer` regarding your variables `i` and `x`. There exist more rows than `Integer` can handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't specify any worksheet. Therefore it acts on the `ActiveSheet`. If you want it to act on Sheet A you must first activate Sheet A. You might do that by calling a dedicated little procedure that first changes the sheet and then calls your existing sub unchanged.

```
Sub CallXiterateMember()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    X_Iterate_Member
End Sub
```

Any more elegant solution would include specifying a sheet in your existing procedure. The easiest way is to use a `With` statement and then just add a period before every reference to it. Since all your references appear to be `Range`, which should become `.Range`, you could achieve that using *Find & Replace*. Here is an example of what your code would look like.

```
Sub X_Iterate_Member()

    Dim i As Long, X As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo ErrExit

    With Ws
        '------------------------Pre-guess X_value to be 0.5h-------------
        For i = 4 To 11
            .Range("B" & i) = .Range("E" & i).Value * 0.5
        Next i


        '------------------------Iteration Loop---------------------------
        i = 4 'Reset i to be 4-th Row

        Do While i < 11 ' Working on Row 4 to 11

            Do While i < 11
                If .Range("B" & i) <> "" And .Range("J" & i) <> 0 Then Exit Do
                i = i + 1
            Loop

        If .Range("B" & i) = "" Or .Range("J" & i) = 0 Then GoTo Increment
        .Range("Q" & i).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=.Range("B" & i)

Increment:

    End With

    Exit Sub
ErrExit:
End Sub
```

If you want to specify the variable `Ws` within your procedure you would have to add

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetA")
```

and then change the worksheet's name before you run the code. More flexible would be if you were to pass `Ws` as an argument in the procedure call, like

```
Sub X_Iterate_Member(Ws As Worksheet)
```

Now you can call your function with the sheet name of your choice, for example as shown below.

```
Sub CallXiterateMember()

    Dim WsName As String

    WsName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, "A").Value
    X_Iterate_Member ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WsName)
End Sub
```

I imagined you would have a Data Validation drop-down in Sheet1!A3 where you select a sheet name. The you press a button to call *CallXiterateMember*. This sub would then read the sheet name from the worksheet and pass it to your modified procedure for processing.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a worksheet for the sheet you are referring to, eg:

```
Sub X_Iterate_Member()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error GoTo Error

Dim i As Integer, X As Integer
Dim ws as worksheet
set ws = thisworkbook.sheets("[SHEET NAME]")
'------------------------Pre-guess X_value to be 0.5h-------------
For i = 4 To 11
    ws.Range("B" & i) = ws.Range("E" & i).Value * 0.5
Next i


'------------------------Iteration Loop---------------------------
i = 4 'Reset i to be 4-th Row

Do While i < 11 ' Working on Row 4 to 11

    Do While i < 11
        If ws.Range("B" & i) <> "" And ws.Range("J" & i) <> 0 Then Exit Do
    i = i + 1
    Loop

If ws.Range("B" & i) = "" Or ws.Range("J" & i) = 0 Then GoTo Increment
ws.Range("Q" & i).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=ws.Range("B" & i)
```